Mantra chanted at the end of Sri Mata Vaishno Devi Aarti
I have been a steadfast devotee of Sri Mata Vaishno Devi. I listen to the Aarti almost everyday on YouTube, where it is streamed live.
Since the past few weeks, I payed some attention to the Mantra chanted at the end of the Aarti, I am unable to understand what the Mantra is. I'm sharing some Aarti links along with timestamps of the Mantra:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHuNMePXYpI (1:49:30 to 1:50:40)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5BR3iMm7mw (1:43:02 to 1:44:12)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbmPjohZrp4 (1:38:33 to 1:39:46)
I would be grateful for help in identifying the Mantra.
Jai Mata Di!

The lines "itanee stuti nish-din, jo nar bhee gaave. kahate sevak dhyaanoo, sukh sampatti" from the Sri Mata Vaishno Devi Aarti mean:

"Itanee stuti nish-din, jo nar bhee gaave": Whoever sings this praise daily...
"Kahate sevak dhyaanoo, sukh sampatti": ...will, as the devotee Dhyan Singh says, attain happiness and prosperity.

This part of the Aarti emphasizes the benefits of devotion and regular worship, suggesting that sincere devotion leads to blessings and well-being.

I don't think you are correct; the quoted mantra is chanted over a minute every time and I'm sure it includes many more lines than you mention.
